# Get specific item in model QML

Tags: qt, qml, listmodel

I can recover an element in my model:

```
property var model: [
{ title: i18n.tr("Standard"), descr: i18n.tr("Style by default"), style:"default" },
{ title: i18n.tr("None"), descr: i18n.tr("Icons without style", style:"none" }
]

ListItem.ItemSelector {
    id: styleIconList
    model: settingsColumn.model
    delegate: OptionSelectorDelegate { 
                property var item: model.modelData ? model.modelData : model
                text: item.title
                subText: item.descr
            }
    onSelectedIndexChanged: {
        launchermodular.settings.iconStyle = model.get(selectedIndex).style //here is problem
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how?

Thank you

Comment: try with: `model[selectedIndex].style`

Comment: For such case I recommend you to use `ListModel`, but add items to it dynamically (for example, with help of Component.onCompleted).